# Indentação Terraform no VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Alguém possui alguma dica de plugin ou forma de configurar o `VSCode` para uma melhor indentação de arquivos `Terraform`?

Dei uma procurada mas não acho muita gente falando sobre porém pelo `Terraform` ser meio chato com indentação queria achar uma forma melhor automatizada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o próprio `terraform` para esta tarefa usando o comando:

```
terraform fmt
```

Isso vai indentar todos os arquivos (`.tf`) naquele diretório.

Se quiser indentar todos os arquivos que estão a partir da raiz (`root dir`) para os subdiretórios utilize o comando:

```
terraform fmt --recursive
```

Para mais informações consulte a [`documentação`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/fmt.html).

Na IDE utilizo a extensão: [`HashiCorp Terraform`](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform) para fazer:

- Destacar as palavras chave da linguagem (`syntax highlight`)
- Auto completar chaves ao declarar módulos e variáveis (`auto complete`)
- Indentação de código acontece com o mesmo comando para formatar códigos em outras linguagens de programação e o atalho é dependente de sistema operacional.

No Linux é (<kbd>CTRL+ALT+i</kbd>)

No MacOS é (<kbd>SHIFT+OPTION+f</kbd>)

No Windows é (<kbd>SHIFT+ALT+f</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Além do próprio Terraform com:

```
terraform fmt -recursive
```

Você pode usar o EditorConfig, que é uma extensão que deixa a configuração de edição de texto configurada, baseada em um arquivo oculto, o site deles é [esse aqui](https://editorconfig.org/).

O Plugin do editorconfig para VS Code [é esse](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig).

E você pode usar a [extensão do VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform) para Syntax Higlighting.

Além disso, você pode configurar o Terragrunt para aplicar a formatação depois dos comandos usando os [after hooks da ferramenta](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/before-and-after-hooks/).